# What's the meaning of '&i' when i := &b

Tags: pointers, go

I'm learning the go, I tried the '&' to get the memory address.But I werid that what's the meaning of '&i',and 'i' came from i := &b , b is a int.

```golang
b := 7
i := &b
fmt.Println(&b) //print => 0xc000088000
fmt.Println(i) //print => 0xc000088000
fmt.Println(&i) //print => 0xc00000e018
```

In this case , What's the meaning of '&i'?

Comment: The code you posted does not match your output, see [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zUbG9WvKe-3). In your code `b` is of type `int` and will be printed simply like `7`. `&b` will be an address, so will be `&i`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: thx for help, fixed it

Comment: `i` is a variable of type `*int`. And `&i` evaluates to a `**int`. Meaning is the same: "take this thing's address"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` is the [address operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), evaluating it results in a memory address, which when passed to the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package, usually the memory address is printed in hexadecimal format ("base 16 notation, with leading 0x").

A memory address is just that: a memory address. It doesn't matter if it's an address of an `int` variable or a `string`, or a variable of a pointer type. When printed, they all look the "same".

The address operator:

> For an operand `x` of type `T`, the address operation `&x` generates a pointer of type `*T` to `x`.

So the address operator gives you a pointer value which when you dereference, you get back the original value.

`&b` will be an address of the variable `b`, of type `*int`, which when you dereference: `*b` will give you (the value of) `b`.

`&i` will be the address of the variable `i`, of type `**int`, which when you dereference: `*i` will give you the value of `i` which is the address of `b`. So if you also dereference that: `**(&i)`, that will also give you (the value of) `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Here `&b` returns address of `b` and the same address is stored in `i`. Since `i` is also a variable `&i` will return the address of variable i.

Answer (score 1):

So `&` operator generates a pointer to it's operand. So `&i` basically generates a pointer to `i` which is already a pointer to `b` which is nothing but a memory address. So when you do `fmt.Println(&i)` it prints the memory address of `i`.